SQL Server out-of-order transactions
I am using SQL Server 2022. I have four "producer" single-threaded applications written in Java (Spring, Hibernate) that inserts data into a single table. Let's say table has column id (primary key) and timestamp. Producer produces data in batches. Each batch results in one or more inserts, executed in transaction.
-- transaction start
INSERT INTO Posts (id, changedAt) VALUES (1, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.100');
-- transaction end
-- transaction start
INSERT INTO Posts (id, changedAt) VALUES (2, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.150');
-- transaction end
-- transaction start
INSERT INTO Posts (id, changedAt) VALUES (3, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.200');
-- transaction end

Then I have a single "consumer" application that in loop executes SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Posts ORDER BY changedAt ASC.
It reads the data, processes it and executes delete on respective rows. Expected behavior is that entries added by a single producer are "visible" in insertion order to a consumer.
Observed behavior is that in some rare cases when there are <200ms delay between subsequent transactions within a single producer, consumer sees entries out of order.
For example, if producer adds rows with ID 1,2,3, consumer on the first SELECT sees 2,3 and on second SELECT he sees 1.
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Posts ORDER BY changedAt ASC
Result: (2, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.150'), (3, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.200')

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Posts ORDER BY changedAt ASC
Result: (1, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.100')

Isolation level is default for SQL Server.
ID is taken from sequence (created by CREATE SEQUENCE statement).
How is this possible?

Please edit your question and provide an MRE demonstrating the consumer's select, example data (with data types), and what result you're getting from that example data versus what you expect. Also, we may need to better understand the timing of how the timestamp and ID are assigned / generated and the record inserted in the producer, so please include that in your MRE.

ensuring order and dirty reads (which is the only thing that sql server's default transaction isolation READ_COMMITTED guarantees to prevent) are not the same thing. what kind of identity do the producers use? is there a schema identity on the PK, or is there maybe a construction like next id = max(id) from table?

@CeeMcSharpface " or is there maybe a construction like next id = max(id) from table?" - I sincerely hope there isn't!!

Updated question, I am using sequence for IDs

If you are using sequence for IDs then order by the ID rather than the timestamp column?

Table and timestamp are reserved keywords. your MRE does not exactly make our life easier :)

Also, INSERT INTO Table (id, timestamp) VALUES (3, '2024-10-01 12:00:00.200'); is not possible if [timestamp] is of type TIMESTAMP because Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column... what is your producer application really executing?

Apologies for those inconsistencies. Thing is that even if I would insert only ID into that table and fetch data using SELECT TOP 10 * ORDER BY Id, I think I would observe same behavior. And I don't understand why results of subsequent transactions are visible as non-linear to the consumer. It of course heavily depends on timing, because eventually consumer will see it all.

Sounds like a race condition. It is possible that transaction1 takes longer to commit than transaction2 and 3. Meanwhile you are selecting rows and not seeing transaction1 because it hasn't yet completed.

It is all executed in a single thread, there cannot be a race condition, at least not in the app.

Then why use three transactions?

do you have async...await requests going on (Futures in Java)? they are race condition prone regardless of the number of threads actually involved, callbacks are quasi parallel and will not enforce any particular order

Let's say you have 3 rows with same date and you fetch TOP 2. Then you might get row 2, 3 and row 1 will be in the next batch, because your sort isn't deterministic enough. You could add ORDER BY Date, ID perhaps

Thank you all for answering. I understand that many factors can be involved and I haven't provided all the details. MRE would be couple of instances of a single threaded app with for-loop throwing inserts and one single threaded app consuming it. I was hoping for some SQL Server related anwer i.e. DB execution engine reorders execution queue in some conditions. @siggemannen I'm aware of that, let's assume that I'm sorting by ID, at the time when consumer query is executed result of T2 are visible althought it completes after T1 (which is not visible yet to the consumer).

couple of instances of a single threaded app > that's processes running in parallel, then. I'd suggest you attach a trace (SQL Profiler) to prove the order the inserts are actually coming along. It might not be translation related at all.
